# jQuery Validate plugin - get two wrappers around error label

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm having some trouble getting my [JQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) up to where I want. My errors display in a sidebox with an arrow. This can be achieved with a single 'wrapper'.

```
$('#loginform').validate({
    errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
        label.addClass('arrow');
        label.insertAfter(element);
    },
    wrapper: 'span'
});
```

The issue is that unfortunately I have a box around my input fields, so the **error should be placed over that border** of that box. To do this, I need two wrappers. So my error should look like this:

```
<span class='errorContainer'>
    <span class='arrow'>
        <span class='error'>This is the actual error message.</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

The current code gives me only this:

```
<span class='arrow'>
    <span class='error'>This is the actual error message.</span>
</span>
```

Comment: You can do something like `$('<span class='errorContainer'></span>').insertAfter(element).append(label)`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
errorPlacement: function(label, element) {
    $('<span class="errorContainer"><span class="arrow"></span></span>').insertAfter(element).find('.arrow').append(label)
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6C4Jm/)

Comment: So simple, and I had so much effort to fix this... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the accepted answer, but I wanted to show a more efficient way to achieve the same desired DOM structure.

Instead of inserting an empty container, finding the inside element, and then appending the error... the following is less verbose and more direct; it just wraps the label with the desired container.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    error.insertAfter(element)
    .wrap('<span class="errorContainer"><span class="arrow"></span></span>');
},
```

This has the advantage of taking the plugin's *default* `errorPlacement` callback...

```
error.insertAfter(element)
```

...and then just chaining the [jQuery `.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method to the end...

```
.wrap('<span class="errorContainer"><span class="arrow"></span></span>')
```

**Working Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/2ZaLB/**

Comment: Thanks, I'm always glad to get extra information about stuff like this. I'm not used to all the jQuery functions so additional info is always handy!